# How to find github pages repo when using custom domain?

Tags: github-pages

I would like to know what is to know what is the github repo of that site:
https://cdn.rtlcss.com/semantic-ui/2.2.6/semantic.rtl.css.

I know that it uses github cause when accessing to https://cdn.rtlcss.com/semantic-ui/2.2.6/, we get github 404.

The reason is that I want to contribute to it.

Answer (score 0):

Found it by looking for rtlcss in github.
https://github.com/RTLCSS/cdn/tree/gh-pages/semantic-ui/2.2.6